# Magento - registry and current category

Tags: session, magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I have a question about `Mage::registry` and `categories:` I'm a on a category page, I retrieve current category by `Mage::registry('current_category')`. I've noticed that it works only for root categories, in fact if I visit a subcategory page I retrieve always the root category with `Mage::registry('current_category')`. So the question is: is something about backend configuration, cache or something else?

Comment: read your post and ask: and what is your question here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OOB, `current_category` is set in `Mage_Catalog` `CategoryController::_initCategory()` (ref [here](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php)) and will *always* be equal to the category currently being viewed.

If your data is different then your app has non-standard functionality or you are seeing cached results.

Comment: Your ref link is dead. And what does OOB mean?

Answer (score 7):

If you are in a template (e.g. `catalog/category/view.phtml`) you can get the current category with

```
$this->getCurrentCategory();
```

If you are in a model, controller or else, try this (found [here](http://indianicorange.wordpress.com/2010/06/18/magento-get-current-category-category-id/)):

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
```

However, `Mage::registry('current_category')` is the normal way to go.

Answer (score 1):

For all categories:-

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
```

For Current Category

```
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
```

Works for me.